# prestashop 1.6 custom theme

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to create very simple prestashop theme for a client. Without any registration and login system. Just 4 pages + page where products are displayed and all that is required to make a purchase.
I already made a copy of default bootrstrap theme, now I need to figure out which .tpl files I can delete. For example can I remove new-products.tpl if my clients doesn't need this functionality, or manufacturer-list.tpl if my clients is selling only self made products.

Comment: Why bother deleting tpl files? There's no harm if they exist. On the other hand if you decide later you want to add and display new features, you're gonna be wasting time by checking which files you deleted and which ones need to be copied into your theme again.

Comment: Well, it is my first time with PrestaShop, all those theme files are a bit overwhelming so i wanted to remove all files that are not required in this project.

Comment: You can remove all files you want, but be sure that you didn't forget to remove all links from your site which refer to that pages

Comment: there is no point deleting any file. just make sure you don't have any links for those pages and no routes are there in Preference > seo & url